# How to pass struct type to module functions?

Tags: go

I just play a little with Go to learn the handling.

I have a main go program.
I created a sub-folder for a database module, in that I want to do database operations.

For the parameters I have a struct type with credentials etc.
How can I pass the struct to the module?

I want all of the configuration and global variables needed in an configuration struct and pass it to the modules if needed.

Is this a good method to achieve the goal?
Thanks for the help.

`./main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    //...
    "github.com/wyrdnixx/go-server/src/go-server/dbapi"
)

func handlerTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("INFO: /test was requested...")
    dbapi.Test(&AppConfig)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", handlerTest)
    AppConfig = ReadConfig()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(AppConfig.ApiPort, nil))
}

type Configuration struct {
    ApiPort    string
    DBHost     string
    DBPort     string
    DBUser     string
    DBPassword string
    DBName     string
    Info       string
}

var AppConfig = Configuration{}

func ReadConfig() Configuration {

    err := gonfig.GetConf("./config.development.json", &AppConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: Config konnte nicht geladen werden: ", err.Error())
    }
    return AppConfig
}
```

`./dbapi/test.go`:

```golang
package dbapi

import (
    // ...
)

func Test (w http.ResponseWriter, Appconfig /* ?!? */) error {
    fmt.Println("Test: " + Appconfig.DBUser)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another package under the main directory, name it `types` or whatever you want. Like bellow:

[image]

Move your `structure` object to `types.go`

```golang
package types

type Configuration struct {
    ApiPort    string
    DBHost     string
    DBPort     string
    DBUser     string
    DBPassword string
    DBName     string
    Info       string
}
```

Now you can access it from both your `main.go` and `dbapi/test.go`.

**main.go:**

```golang
package main

import "... .../code/types"

func handlerTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("INFO: /test was requested...")
    dbapi.Test(&AppConfig)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", handlerTest)
    AppConfig = ReadConfig()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(AppConfig.ApiPort, nil))
}


var AppConfig = types.Configuration{}

func ReadConfig() types.Configuration {

    err := gonfig.GetConf("./config.development.json", &AppConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: Config konnte nicht geladen werden: ",     err.Error())
    }
    return AppConfig
}
```

**dbapi.go:**

```golang
package dbapi

import "... .../code/types"

func Test (w http.ResponseWriter, Appconfig *types.Configuration) error {
    fmt.Println("Test: " + Appconfig.DBUser)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppConfig on your Test function of type Configuration struct, which you have declared on your main package. Since go doesn't support cyclic dependencies, you can not import Configuration struct into the dbapi package to use it there. So, I would move Configuration struct from the main package and declare it in the dbapi package.

```
package dbapi

import (...)

type Configuration struct {
    ApiPort    string
    DBHost     string
    DBPort     string
    DBUser     string
    DBPassword string
    DBName     string
    Info       string
}


func Test (w http.ResponseWriter, Appconfig *Configuration) error {
    fmt.Println("Test: " + Appconfig.DBUser)
}
```

And then, you can use the Configuration struct inside main, by importing it from the dbapi package.

```
var AppConfig = dbapi.Configuration{}
```

So, your main package would look like this:

```
package main

import(
...
"github.com/wyrdnixx/go-server/src/go-server/dbapi"
)

func handlerTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("INFO: /test was requested...")
    dbapi.Test(&AppConfig)
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", handlerTest)
    AppConfig = ReadConfig()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(AppConfig.ApiPort, nil))  
}

var AppConfig = dbapi.Configuration{}

func ReadConfig() dbapi.Configuration {

    err := gonfig.GetConf("./config.development.json", &AppConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: Config konnte nicht geladen werden: ",     err.Error())
    } 
    return dbapi.AppConfig
}
```

Comment: I guess you're missing `dbapi` in `func ReadConfig() dbapi.Configuration`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The Configs are read at the main package and passed to the test function in the dbapi package.

Comment: @Mania take a look at the output of `ReadConfig()` function inside your main package. You can't access `Configuration` structure directly.